# UIButton frame size doesn't update to support increased font size from settings

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibutton, autolayout

I have a basic UIButton with the following constraints:

[image: UIButton autolayout constraint dynamic text font size]

I have some basic trailing and top constraints and I have a >= width and height constraint set to 48 as I want 48 to be my minimum width and height for the button.

My goal is to have the text in button grow as the user changes their font size from settings.

This text in the button seems to be increasing in size, however, the frame doesn't seem to be updating to accomodate that increase.

[image]

This is what I mean setting the font size from control panel
[image: Dynamic text font size control panel iOS Swift]

However, if I quit the app and launch it again, the frame size is calculated correctly and on changing the text size from the control panel seems to make the font size in button shrink and grow appropriately.

[image: UIButton frame size increase]

It seems as if a max width / height needs to be determined first.

In the code I even set this:

```
skipButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.font(forTextStyle: .body, fontName: .suecaNanoRegular, size: 14)
skipButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
```

How can I get my UIButton to support dynamic font sizes at run time.

Here are my other button settings if that helps with debugging.

[image: UIButton settings storyboard dynamic text size font swift iOS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your font is not itself dynamic.

Delete your code about the title label, and reconfigure the button in the storyboard to be Plain style instead of Default style, and give it a dynamic font setting, as shown in this screen shot:

[image]

The button title font size will then behave as you expect.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this and using system fonts would work, however my requirement is to use a custom font. I did see that Apple supports this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically/ - however I could not get this to work as desired.

Comment: Also another button with the same font seems to be scaling in size which has a bigger width and height constraint so its leading me to believe that I am not setting the constraints up correctly.

Comment: If you want to use a custom font you need to pass it through UIFontMetrics. But then you cannot configure it in the storyboard, and your code is not how you do it either.

Comment: And it has nothing to do with constraints. It's the font, as my answer tells you.

Comment: Please have a look at my updated / corrected question. It seems the font size is increasing, but the frame doesn't accomodate it.

Comment: I answered the question you asked. I showed you a configuration that works and I provided a screencast that proves it. If you want to ask a different question, fine.

Comment: By the way, if you care to read the docs you will see that they agree with me. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically Try doing what I said before simply rejecting it. I use dynamic self sizing buttons all day long, I know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks Matt, you indeed were right and this did solve the issue. The issue is though, it seems that the settings of vertical and horizontal alignment that I've set in storyboard seem to be ignored after changing to the Plain style.

Comment: We can certainly talk about how to fix that but it is _not what you asked_. I answered the question you asked. Part of my solution to making the button automatically respond to the user's dynamic type size choices is to make it a configuration based button. You will need to treat it as such.

Comment: fair enough, thanks for your answer and support Matt. Would you like me to create a seperate question for that or can we solve that here ?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration for more about how to live in the modern button world.

Comment: By the way your content horizontal and vertical alignment settings _do_ work on my machine. As long as your minimum width/height is bigger than the font size, the text appears in the top right corner of the button as desired. Try changing the button to a `filled` button temporarily so you can see the text against the button bounds. You might have to change the alignment to something else and then change it back again in the storyboard in order to get it to work but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me...

Add a button to Storyboard, change **only 3 properties**:

- Style: Default
- Title: Skip
- Background: Yellow (so we can see the framing at run-time)

Constraints:

[image]

[image]

Added a random font to my project - "Gotham-BookItalic.otf"

View Controller class:

```
class DynamicFontVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var skipButton: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let customFont = UIFont(name: "Gotham-BookItalic", size: 14.0) else {
            fatalError("Could not load font!")
        }
        
        skipButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body).scaledFont(for: customFont)
        skipButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    }
    
}
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Edit** -- with Control Alignment set to Trailing / Top:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solution seems on the right track, however, it does seem to have some padding to the top and trailing, atleast initially. Perhaps this is the inset ? Ideally, I'd want it to always stick to the top, trailing corner of the yellow box.

Comment: @ShawnFrank - I hadn't set the Control Alignment. Set that as you showed in your post image, and the Title will "stick to the Top and Trailing" and still handle the size changes.

Comment: Thanks DonMag, I'll give this a try shortly.